# Finding the minimum and maximum values of f(x)=x+(1/x)

Tags: derivatives

So basically the question is to find the minimum value of the sum

$$f(x)=x+(1/x)$$

for any real number $x$.

I differentiated the function and found the values of $x$ for which $f'(x)=0$ as $-1$ and $1$.

Using the second derivative test I find that maximal is $-1$ and minimal is $+1$.
But isn't this counter intuitive? Like, mere substitution tells us $f(-1)$ has a lower value than $f(1)$. Also if it is for any real number, shouldn't the minimal be at $x=-\infty$ and maxima at $x=\infty$?

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You're forgetting about the discontinuity at $x=0$. ($1/x$ isn't defined at $0$).  Your intuition fails you because anything can happen as you cross an infinite discontinuity.

Comment: Are you asked to find the *global* extrema or the *local* extrema?  You've found both (the local extrema are at $x=-1$ and $x=1$), and the global maximum and minimum don't exist.

Comment: It isn't mentioned which to find. The options involve only integers though, so I guess they're referring to the local minima. Is it like x=1 is the minima of the upper disjointed part and x=(-1) is the maxima of the lower part?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Using the second derivative test I find that maximal is -1 and minimal
>   is +1. But isn't this counter intuitive?

A short look on the graph hints that only local extrema seem to exist:

[image]

So what you found are the function values of the local extrema, meaning they are extremal regarding a neighbourhood around them and might not (as it is the case here) extremal regarding the whole domain.

> Also if it is for any real number, shouldn't the minimal be at
>   $x=-\infty$ and maxima at $x=\infty$?

The infinite points are not part of the domain, so they are not considered. This function has no (global) minimum or (global) maximum.

Answer (score 1):

[image]
$f(x)=x+\frac 1x$

$x_{\max}=-1, y(-1)=-2; x_{\min}=1, y(1)=2$